# UILabel border color with percentage

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I want to color my UILabel border. But I want to do it part by part,, not the whole border. This is the thing that I want to do.
[image]

According to the percentage, I want to color my `UILabel` border.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: get two layers, draw hollow gray circle on one and another with hollow blue circle. For the blue circle you will need draw according to the percentage. add these layers on top of your view's original layer.

Comment: Why don't you use a library like this for example: https://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom subclass of UILabel.

In the initWithCoder method of your custom label, add 2 CAShapeLayer objects to your label.

Set one to draw in your dark blue and the other to draw in your light blue.

Install a CGPath in each one which is a full circle.

Manipulate the strokeStart and strokeEnd of each shape layer to draw the desired parts of each circle.